# Finding the smallest-cost way to deliver goods

Tags: graphs, reductions, minimum-spanning-tree

I want to deliver products from various sources to various destinations such that the overall cost is minimized. We need to deliver these products while obeying our contractual obligatione with each supplier. In particular, each supplier ("source") specifies a minimum and maximum quantity of the product that should be taken from them (i.e. the "minimum" indicates that we must purchase *at least* that amount, whereas the "maximum" indicates that we must take no more than that amount). So the sum of the minimums is less than the sum of the total product we must provide, and the sum of the total product we must provide is less than the sum of the maximums.

My manager tells me that they have computer code that can solve the capacitated minimum spanning tree problem (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitated_minimum_spanning_tree). Using this as a oracle, how can you determine a method to determine which supplier(s) should deliver their products to which destination(s) at a lowest total cost (or explain why it can't be used to solve the problem)? I'm provided with the costs $c_{i, j}$ of transporting from source $i$ to destination $j$, and I'm also provided with the minimum and maximum quantities of product to be taken from each supplier.

---

This is a practice problem that I encountered while studying NP completeness and reductions.

I know that I need to somehow construct a graph to pass into the blackbox but coming up with the graph is the tricky part. I thought about constructing a graph with all of the $c_{i, j}'s$ as edge weights, but then I can't get the maximum and minimum quantities to come into play. I've thought about this problem for a while now, but I still can't figure it out. Does anyone have any suggestions? This reduction seems a lot more complicated than the other ones I've seen, or maybe I'm just overthinking it?

Comment: Are the minimum and maximum supply quantities integers ? Do the destinations require variable number of products ? Is there any limit on the problem dimension ? number of suppliers, destination, supplying minimum and maximum ...

Comment: Yes, the minimum and maximum are integers. Yes, the destinations require variable numbers of products. Also, the minimum and maximum are variable (depending on the source). I am provided with five sources and six destinations. However, I don't actually have to solve the problem --- I just want to understand the reduction/set up to solve it.

Comment: If we transport $q_{i,j}$ quantity from $i$ to $j$, is the associated cost $c_{i,j}$ or $c_{i,j}\cdot q_{i,j}$?

Comment: $c_{i, j} \times q_{i, j}$